# iOS Storyboard - Positioning two tableViews

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a viewController, with a navigation bar, and two tableviews, each taking up half of the viewControllers width (160x568). When I add a prototype cell to each one, the first tableviewcell is displayed in the correct position, right below the navigation bar. However, when I add a cell to the second tableview, the cell is beneath/under/covered up by the navigation bar.

I'm not sure why this is. Any insight?

[image: TableViewCell underneath NavigationBar]

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful...

Comment: Why are you using two tableviews? Does it actually make sense to be doing this? You'll have two tables that don't scroll in sync with one another unless you do some work. Would it make more sense for you to do a UICollectionView instead?

Comment: Yes, I would rather them scroll separately.

Comment: I can't find anything against this in the Human Interactions Guidelines, but I haven't ever seen this done in any app on a ViewController. The closest I've seen is a master-detail but the tables are in separate VCs. I would rethink your UI/UX because this is going to not only cause confusion for users but also start making your code complex. You'd need to have extra logic in your tableView delegates just to see which tableView you're looking at (numberOfRows, cellForRow, didSelectRow, numberOfSections, etc).